# The /users/{id}/timeline route is reporting incorrect totals

Tags: bug, status-completed, api, timeline

It seems that the `/users/{id}/timeline` route is returning an incorrect total. For example, the following URL is reporting a total of `1607` items:

> http://api.stackapps.com/1.1/users/7789/timeline

...and yet there are clearly only 4 events in the `user_timelines` property. I tried a few other user IDs and they are all returning the number `1607`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a fun one.

Turned out there was a bug in cache for counts, that only affected this particular method.  It has been fixed.